Where most species are absent from most samples, use zeros or leave cells empty?
I have a dataset of 110 avian diet samples containing a couple hundred insect species. Most species are absent from most samples. I'm unclear on whether I should enter zeroes where a species is absent or leave the cell empty. Any thoughts? My goal is to subject the data to Detrended Correspondence Analysis, to look at co-occurrence of certain species and similarity between samples.

If the observed value for a species is truly 0, why do you think that it should just be removed? I'm not sure about Detrended Correspondence Analysis, but many analysis methods by default simply discard an observation (meaning the entire sample in your scenario, with all of its species counts) if there are any missing values in the components.

Good question...I have confidence that the species was really absent in those cases. I just worry what a huge number of zeroes in the data set will do to the analysis--you are certainly right that I would not want the sample to be discarded from the analysis!

A count-based model, like a Poisson generalized linear model, expects there to be true 0 values among the observations if the mean count values are small. The 0 values are needed for proper analysis.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thanks for your comments, they are clarifying for me. I'm flailing toward a solution, bit by bit. Yes, they are count-based data, a matrix of 110 dietary samples by a couple hundred species in the diet. Many of the species occur only once in the diet, so in the end I may end up doing the analsis simply deleting them--I'll try it with and without. (although they often co-occur in the same dietary samples, which is interesting). I'm using an old version of SYSTAT which is limited in what it can do.

A pair of correlation or association matrices on species and samples might be adequate, by with a lot of zeros and with many species occurring in a "feast or famine" pattern, with huge numbers in a few cells and zero to very few in others, I need a non-linear measure of association. My SYSTAT has some nonparametric measures of association, but the program doesn't give me P-values for them like it does for Pearson's r, which I probably shouldn't use.

I may end up getting a new copy of PC-ORD or more recent version of SYSTAT if I can afford either. (definitely not R, I don't have time to learn it from scratch). I'm slowly grappling my way through these issues, I'll probably come back for more advice later, gotta go to southern Mexico quite soon for some research.
